# Watermark as 2D barcode

Tags: image-processing, watermark

Looking for a solution to this scenario where visible 2D barcode is not allowed.

Given the below page structure (A4 landscape, 65% excel table, 2 very small vector graphic logos)...

I want to impeded at most 512 bytes of binary data, independent to the page contents such that after printing it (laser gray scale) I can retrieve all the impeded data from a scanned version.

[image]

is watermark possible? the requirement is simple no crop or big rotation involved... if yes is there an open source library of this watermark algorithm?

Comment: I didn't understand your question! What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: extract my embedded data from scanned page without using visible 2D barcode

Comment: I don't know some easy commands for "invisible" watermarking, but there are lots of ways for watermarking which you can implement with OpenCV library. One of the best choices is using wavelet decomposition (fusing DWT of the host image and the watermark), which is totally invisible and kind of secure.